# Custom dialog/popup within main window/stage with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Is it possible to create a custom dialog in JavaFX which isn't an OS-level window?  (It would be a popup window displayed over top everything else on the main stage, which can't leave the application window.)  i.e. An Adobe/Apache Flex style dialog, for anyone familiar.

Comment: ControlsFX used to have this feature ([see lightweight dialogs](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/dialogs/)).  However, recent builds of ControlsFX [dropped the lightweight dialog feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341152/controlsfx-dialogs-deprecated-for-what).  Instead, ControlsFX now uses only the dialogs implemented in the JavaFX core API, which are self-contained stages.  You might wish to review some [old branch source code of ControlsFX](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/branches/) to see how they achieved their original lightweight dialog implementation.

Comment: ControlsFX [lightweight dialog source implementation](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/src/371bca0e905536ca6742d181fdade07258260659/controlsfx/src/main/java/org/controlsfx/dialog/LightweightDialog.java?at=8.0.6_20&fileviewer=file-view-default) (now unsupported).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually quite easy and without a need to use 3rd party library:

Embed your root container within **stackpane** and over the top put **anchor pane** , create dialog box control(container/containers+controls).

To demonstrate what i mean here is a small fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<StackPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: black;" />
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="363.0">
         <children>
            <BorderPane layoutX="84.0" layoutY="123.0" prefHeight="99.0" prefWidth="227.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;">
               <center>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
               </center>
            </BorderPane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

Looks like :
[image]

You can make it moveable with properties,listener. It will require some work bud its doable.

Bud as jewelsea mentioned controlsfx has already what you need implemented, if i remember correctly they also provided controlfx samples jar where you can see sourcecode and all the included stuff in action, first take a look at that if anything in there fits your needs.Its really trivial to then implement it from that point on, i only had trouble in a past with one of theyr controls when i updated to new version of java.

Comment: Don't really need it to be movable, just a static container like that should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the X and Y property. Here is how I update the position of dialog base on the root stage position.

```
public static Stage getStage() {
    return StageHelper.getStages().get(0);
}

public static void stayInRootStage(Dialog dialog) {

    Window window = dialogPane.getScene().getWindow();
    Stage mainStage = getStage();

    ChangeListener<Number> yListener = new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            double newY = mainStage.getY() + mainStage.getHeight() / 2 - dialog.getHeight() / 2;
            dialog.setY(newY);

        }
    };

    ChangeListener<Number> xListener = new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            double newX = mainStage.getX() + mainStage.getWidth() / 2 - dialog.getWidth() / 2;
            dialog.setX(newX);
        }

    };

    mainStage.getScene().getWindow().yProperty().addListener(yListener);

    mainStage.getScene().getWindow().xProperty().addListener(xListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog();

dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).