# In Javafx how to create floating sub-stages that stay on top only when using the app?

Tags: javafx

In my javafx app I want to have some 'floating' sub-stages: they are non-modal and stay on top of the main stage when I use the app (they lose focus but dont hide).

I tried `Stage::setAlwaysOnTop` (along with setting their onwer to the main stage), but in that case these sub-stages would still stay on top when I click on & bring up some other application to cover the main stage.

I only need them to stay on-top-of the main stage, rather than all the other windows in the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description, what I think you want is a modeless child stage:

```
Stage childStage = new Stage(); 
childStage.initOwner(parentStage);
childStage.initModality(Modality.NONE);  
childStage.show();
```

From the [Stage](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initOwner(javafx.stage.Window)) documentation:

> A stage can optionally have an owner Window. When a window is a stage's owner, it is said to be the parent of that stage.
>
> Owned Stages are tied to the parent Window. An owned stage will always be on top of its parent window. When a parent window is closed or iconified, then all owned windows will be affected as well. Owned Stages cannot be independently iconified.

**Example**

A modeless child utility stage that is always shown on top of a parent stage.

[image: child stage]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class OverlayApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane parentLayout = new StackPane(new Button("Parent"));
        parentLayout.setBackground(Background.fill(Color.LIGHTBLUE));
        parentLayout.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 40px;");
        parentLayout.setPrefSize(600, 400);
        parentLayout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(parentLayout));

        Stage childStage = new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        childStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
        childStage.initModality(Modality.NONE);

        StackPane childLayout = new StackPane(new Button("Child"));
        childLayout.setBackground(Background.fill(Color.PALEGREEN));
        childLayout.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 40px;");
        childLayout.setPrefSize(300, 200);
        childLayout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        childStage.setScene(new Scene(childLayout));

        primaryStage.show();

        childStage.setX(primaryStage.getX() + primaryStage.getWidth() * 1 / 4);
        childStage.setY(primaryStage.getY() + primaryStage.getHeight() * 3 / 4);
        childStage.show();
    }
}
```

The example uses [`StageStyle.UTILITY`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/StageStyle.html#UTILITY), which is common for these types of child stages.  Other stage styles can be applied, but, as noted, the minify button for the child stage will be disabled or not present because the child stage cannot be separately iconified from the parent stage.  Usually, to get around that, the child stage can be hidden and shown as needed, using controls within the application.

**Related**

JavaFX has no concept of a "sub-stage". There is a thing called a [`SubScene`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/SubScene.html#:%7E:text=The%20SubScene%20class%20is%20the,scene%20or%20another%20sub%2Dscene.), but that is different from what you describe.

ControlsFX had a somewhat similar feature, named [lightweight dialogs](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.controlsfx/controlsfx/8.0.4/org/controlsfx/dialog/Dialogs.html),  that is for rendering overlay dialogs in the context of a single scene graph. However the ControlsFX lightweight dialogs implementation was [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341152/controlsfx-dialogs-deprecated-for-what).

The example in this answer differs from a full [Multiple Document Interface (MDI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-document_interface).  MDI is like a complete windowing system within an application.  With MDI, the child windows of the MDI interface are only visible within the context of the parent window, and the child windows can be separately iconified and restored.

An example of an API for creating MDI-style interfaces is the Swing [`JDesktopPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) for internal frames.  This might be usable from JavaFX as JavaFX has a Swing bridge.  However, I would caution against trying such an integration as you may encounter various unforeseen difficulties when doing so.

Comment: Exactly what I need. I should've read the Stage doc more carefully.  :(